# Using `useStore` API with vuex 4.x

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

1. Follow the official example to export your own `useStore`, and then use it in the component.

```
import { createStore, Store,  useStore as baseUseStore } from 'vuex';

export const key: InjectionKey<Store<RootState>> = Symbol();

export function useStore() {
  return baseUseStore(key);
}
```

use in the component

```
setup() {
  const store = useStore();
  const onClick = () => {
    console.log(store)
    store.dispatch('user/getUserInfo');
  }
  return {
    onClick,
  }
},
```

2. After running, `store` is undefined.
3. It can be obtained normally when I use it in the `methods` attribute

```
methods: {
  login() {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/getToken')
  }
}
```

4. why? how to fix it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that [simplifying `useStore` usage](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#simplifying-usestore-usage) tutorial, you still need to register the `store` and `key` in *main.ts* as they did.  You will get undefined if you don't do this:

```js
// main.ts
import { store, key } from './store'

const app = createApp({ ... })

// pass the injection key
app.use(store, key)
```

The reason is that `baseUseStore(key)` has no meaning until that's done.